# How can I configure build path of hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

```
public class hibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        UserDetails user=new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("Ujash");

        try
        {
            Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            System.out.println("Cfg and hbm files loaded succesfully"); 
        }
        catch(Excaption ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Your are going wrong way");
        }
        Session session=sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

ScreenShot
[image: Screenshot of IDE showing error]

I am using PostgreSQL for the database

Comment: Which is nothing to do with JPA API. Kindly remove that tag

Comment: cannot find what compile time error is it , can you hover over the read line and give us some details . apart from that build path thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {

        File cfgFile = new File("pathToFile/hibernate.cfg.xml");

        return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(cfgFile).buildSessionFactory();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {

        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

and this class you can access

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you miss `buildSessionFactory()` method call.

You need to do a configuration this way and use `sessionFactory` to open a session.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

About your question. You didn't get sense of "Configure build path"
. It is not about `hibernate.cfg.xml`. You just need to add Hibernate libraries to the class path or (if you already do it) import `Configuration` class.

You can download a [simply](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate-mysql) Eclispe project and get libraries for Hibernate 4 or Hibernate 5 from there.

The best way is to use Maven or Gradle build and specify libraries in the `pom.xml` or in the [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/build.gradle#L43).